How can I configure Ceedling for a project using the IAR compiler?
I have an embedded project that is compatible with the IAR compiler (iccarm). I already have a project.yml file from here. project.yml
Ceedling compiles my project without any problems and saves the .o files in build/test/out.
In the next step the iar linker crashes with the following error:
Building Objects
----------------
Compiling test_crc.c...
Compiling test_crc::crc.c...
Compiling test_crc::unity.c...
Compiling test_crc::cmock.c...
Compiling test_crc::test_crc_runner.c...

Building Test Executables
-------------------------
Linking test_crc.out...
EXCEPTION: ShellExecutionException ==> 'Iar Test Linker' (ilinkarm) terminated with exit code [3] and output >> "IAR ELF Linker V9.20.4.327/W64 for ARM
   Copyright 2007-2022 IAR Systems AB.
Fatal error[Ms007]: could not open file "build/test/out/test_crc/test_crc.o bui
          ld/test/out/test_crc/crc.o build/test/out/test_crc/test_crc_runner.o
          build/test/out/test_crc/unity.o build/test/out/test_crc/cmock.o"
            Directories searched:
              D:\prj\uebungen\c\hmi-tests
              D:\prj\uebungen\c\hmi-tests\build\test\out\test_crc
Fatal error detected, aborting."
Ceedling could not complete operations because of errors

My files have the correct read and write permissions and I have admin rights on Windows 10.
When I try a normal C project with gcc compiler and ceedling everything works. When I try a normal C project with IAR compiler and Ceedling the same error occurs.
So I believe there is a problem with my configuration in project.yml
Has anyone had a similar problem? Thank you for your help!

It looks like it is trying to open a string containing multiple filenames separated by spaces as if it were a single filename.  I'm not familiar with how the tool you are using calls the linker but perhaps you need to separate some arguments into a list.  It could be as simple as removing excess quotes.
